# How to store JSON data from API call

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

I'm a novice programmer so feel free to comment on things that make no sense so that I can learn.

I'm working on a coffee shop finder android app that makes calls to the [SimpleGeo](http://simplegeo.com) API to get each place of interest.  I'm having trouble thinking up a way to store the returned JSON data in a way that I can use for my purposes.  I need to do 2 things with the data: first, I need a map overlay class to access it so I can draw markers for each coffee shop (which I'm okay with); second, I need to display the data in a list view.

The API call:

```
    /** Queries SimpleGeo with current location **/
    private void getJSONData() {
    SimpleGeoPlacesClient client = SimpleGeoPlacesClient.getInstance();
    client.getHttpClient().setToken(oauth_key, oauth_secret);
    double radius = 25;
    try {
        client.search(lat, lng, "coffee", null, radius,
                new FeatureCollectionCallback() {
                    public void onSuccess(FeatureCollection collection) {
                        try {
                            features = collection.toJSON();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Parsing the data:

```
    private void parseJSONData() throws JSONException {
    for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject feature = features.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(
                "feature");
    }
}
```

I'm currently trying to create java objects out of the data using GSON outlined in [this](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/) tutorial.  Would SQLite be appropriate for this?  Any pro-tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with android, you can use google map view

view,com.google.android.maps.MapView
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

and ListView 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

I dont see how SQLite fits in here , unless you plan to store the places across app restarts.
All you need to do is extract place information from JSON and do whatever you want with that data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have my map view and list view already set up.  The list view currently points to a dummy array and the map is functioning.  The main problem is that I'm not sure of the best way to deal with the JSON data.  Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: you'll have to elaborate on what you mean by "deal with json".Do you want to store it on disk ? are you having trouble extracting information from JSON ? etc ...

Comment: I do want to store the information so that I can avoid unnecessary API calls.  That is why I thought SQLite might fit the scenario.  I am trying to use gson to extract the information into a java object which I can then use to draw a map overlay and also create an array which I can display in a list view.  What I should have asked is does this method make sense from an android development perspective?  Can you foresee any problems with this technique?  These questions might seem trivial because I have never attempted using any of these methods.

Comment: I think it is a pretty standard practice to store JSON data either in a text file or if truly necessary , in SQLite. I haven't used GSON , it looks like it is a useful library , if that doesn't work you can always switch back to extracting by hand and mapping to the required Class.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I know the question is vague.  It can be a challenge wording the question when I don't know a lot about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that an answer was already accepted, but I'm tossing my 2 bits in, anyhow...

It may not be that the response JSON needs be persisted (in SQLite or a text file), in order to "avoid unnecessary API calls."  More information about the app would be needed to determine this.

Copying from a blog post my friend asked me to proofread:

> In some situations, GSON makes it fantastically simple to create Java objects from JSON, though many of the examples (especially those in blog posts) are lamely trivial or unnecessarily complex, often being little more than copy-paste examples (with names changed) from the GSON documentation, which is the heart of the problem - the docs aren't very thorough in their examples, and they quickly make it seem like complex objects are complicated to map.

But I digress...

If the problem is that one doesn't know how to use JSON and/or GSON, this does not imply that the solution involves SQLite or text file persistence or any kind of persistence.

Regarding the code in the original question, it looks like it assumes that objects in the response JSON will appear in some particular order.  It's my experience that this is often not a safe assumption to make.  Sometimes itemX comes first, sometimes it comes third.  (This of course depends on the system generating the response.)  So, parse the result allowing for the order of JSON objects to vary.

Regarding whether to persist the JSON data, again, more would need to be known about the app than what was explained, so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is probably a good place for the programming help conversations.  Considering you already accepted an answer to the original question, what other questions do you have?